# Open device flashlight in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I work on react native app and I want open and close device flashlight. It is possible without any camera module?

Comment: https://aboutreact.com/turn-on-off-flashlight-to-make-a-torch-app-in-react-native/

Comment: When i use react-native-torch i get error[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Torch.switchState')]                                                                       Camera permissions is granted also

Comment: You can refer this [demo](https://github.com/ludo/TorchDemo) or use this [code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-torch#with-extra-permission-check-and-dialog-android-only)

Comment: rebuilding app may works react-native run-android then try it should work

Comment: May the problem is the 'react-native-torch' in not work with expo in development build mode?

Comment: @χρηστοςαπατσιδης Did you link a native dependency successfully?